# Wrong calculations for joint density function?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Q: Suppose $X$ and $Y $have joint density $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = c$ for all $x, y$ satisfying:

$0<y<x<1$ or (union) $0<y<1-x$ and $0<x<1$. Find c.

I know that:

$$\int \int f_{X, Y}(x, y) dx dy = 1$$

So I split it into 2 sections:

$$\int_0^{1-x} \int_0^1 c dx dy + \int_{1-x}^x \int_{0.5}^1 c dx dy = c - 0.5c = 0.5c = 1$$

which means $c=2$

But I've a final answer of $c=4/3$ (which does make more sense). What did I do wrong?

As requested I've split my area to green and blue triangles.

[image]

Comment: $0<y<x<1$ means $y$ should integrate up to $x$ as $x$ integrates from $0$ to $1$

Comment: @kevinkayaks This is one option right, but what's wrong with my division? I took the big triangle between y=0, x=0 and y=1-x and the small triangle between x=1, y=x, y=1-x they don't overlap and they give the whole space

Comment: Draw a picture of the $x$-$y$-area you are integrating that constant over. What is the area? Easy to see.

Comment: I can't make any sense of your calculations. First of all, your double integrals are inside out: you've written $dx$ in the inner integral but then you use $x$ for the bounds of the outer integral. Then you get $c$ for the value of one integral (how?) and then $-0.5c$ (what???) for the other.

Comment: @DavidK "but then you use  for the bounds of the outer integral" that's not correct, x values from 0 to 1 and 0.5 to 1, y depend on x that's why I have y from 0 to (1-x). calculate the integral by yourself for the left integral the value of the inner one is c then you get c*(1-x).

Comment: @KurtG. I did, see my question for an image.

Comment: It is easy to see that area=3/4, so c=4/3.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I know that, but I'm rather asking what's wrong with my method...

Comment: It looks to me that the method  is correct, but you made a mistake in carrying out the integral.  The first one = c/2 and the second = c/4.

Comment: You're simply doing the integral wrong, although you're thinking about it correctly based on your diagram. David K and Herb are both correct. The way you have $x$ in the limit of your outer integral makes no sense. Following what you wrote correctly, your answer would depend on $x$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with
$$
W = \int_0^{1-x} \int_0^1 c\, dx\, dy + \int_{1-x}^x \int_{0.5}^1 c\, dx\, dy
$$
I write $W$ for convenience to name the total you're trying to integrate.

As you understood correctly, because $\int_0^1 c\, dx = c$ and
$\int_{0.5}^1 c\, dx = \frac12 c,$ the two integrals that compose $W$ are exactly equal to
$$
W = \int_0^{1-x} c\, dy + \int_{1-x}^x \frac12 c\, dy
$$

Notice now that $x$ appears only in the bounds of the integrals now. The boundaries of $x$ in the formerly inner integrals are **gone**, as if they never existed. In particular, the $dx$s in the inner integrals have **nothing to do** with the $x$s on the outer integrals. The fact that the same letters are used in both places is merely an unfortunate coincidence and a temptation to make errors; we could just as well have replaced $dx$ by $du$ and written
$$
\int_0^{1-x} \int_0^1 c\, du\, dy + \int_{1-x}^x \int_{0.5}^1 c\, du\, dy
$$
and this too would be exactly equal to $W.$

So now you are simply integrating constants over variable intervals:

$$ \int_0^{1-x} c\, dy = c(1 - x) $$
and
$$ \int_{1-x}^x \frac12 c\, dy = \frac12 c((1 - x) - x) = c\left(\frac12 - x\right). $$

Therefore

$$ W = c(1 - x) + c\left(\frac12 - x\right) = c\left(\frac32 - 2x\right). $$

And that's it. $W$ as calculated here is a function of an independent variable $x$ which (I remind you) is completely unrelated to the variable coincidentally called $x$ inside the original inner integrals.

But you need $W$ to be a number depending only on $c.$

---

That's the evaluation of what you **wrote**. But this is what you **drew**:
$$
V = \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} c\, dy\, dx + \int_{0.5}^1 \int_{1-x}^x c\, dy\, dx.
$$

Now the $x$s in the integral bounds are the same $x$s that appear in the $dx$s.
That's because $\int_0^{1-x} c\, dy = g(x)$ for some function $g$
and $\int_{1-x}^x c\, dy = h(x)$ for some function $h,$
and the integrals integrate these two functions over the fixed intervals
$[0,1]$ and $\left[\frac12,1\right]$:
$$
V = \int_0^1 g(x)\, dx + \int_{0.5}^1 h(x)\, dx.
$$

That is, in the left integral $g(x)$ integrates $c$ along the vertical cross-section of the larger triangle in your drawing for each value of $x$ between $0$ and $1,$
and in the right integral $h(x)$ integrates $c$ along the vertical cross-section of the smaller triangle in your drawing for each value of $x$ between $0$ and $\frac12.$
Between these two integrals you integrate $c$ everywhere within the two triangles, which is exactly the region over which $f_{X, Y}(x, y) = c.$

As it turns out,
$$
g(x) = \int_0^{1-x} c\, dy = c(1 - x)
$$
and
$$
h(x) = \int_{1-x}^x c\, dy = c(2x - 1).
$$

Then
$$
V = \int_0^1 c(1 - x)\, dx + \int_{0.5}^1 c(2x - 1)\, dx = \frac34 c.
$$
So what you drew leads to a correct answer if it is transcribed correctly into double integrals.
Writing double integrals in the correct order really does matter.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand, in both cases for $W$ and $V$ you wrote (referring to left part) that x is from 0 to 1, and y from 0 to (1-x), so why the order for $W$ is wrong while for $V$ it's right? yet in both cases dx matches the integral from 0 to 1 and dy matches the integral from 0 to (1-x)

Comment: It's because if you want the $x$ on the integral over $dy$ to have anything to do with the $x$ of the integral over $dx,$ the $x$ has to be **inside** the $dx$ integral. Any $x$ outside the $dx$ integral is an unrelated variable. That's simply how the meaning of integrals is defined.

Comment: Another way to look at it is, the **outer** integral in a double integral can tell the **inner** integral what the values of variables are, but the inner integral cannot tell the outer integral what the values of variables are. It just like how the United States can make a law that California has to follow, but California cannot make a law that the United States has to follow.

Comment: Thanks, and I couldn't understand this as well "In particular, the 
s in the inner integrals have nothing to do with the 
s on the outer integrals." why it's not the same x, I mean how did you conclude that? it makes more sense to refer to them as same x... we are talking about x in the graph...

Comment: First, it's good to use variables whose names remind you of how you intend to use them. For example, $dx$ to integrate in a direction parallel to the $x$ axis. But there are a lot of things we might measure parallel to the $x$ axis, and we can't call them all $x$ at the same time. Second, in this case the $x$ outside the $\int dx$ is a different thing from $x$ in the $\int dx$ because that's part of the definition of an integral.

Comment: If you write computer programs, think of $\int dx$ as a function where $x$ is a local variable. You know you can define another variable named $x$ outside the function, but the function will neither look at the value of that variable nor write to it when you use the local variable $x$ inside the function. They really are just two different things that (confusingly) have been named the same.

Comment: "Second, in this case the 
 outside the ∫
 is a different thing from 
 in the ∫
 because that's part of the definition of an integral" This is the part I couldn't understand, why it's different

Comment: First, I should have said I'm only talking about definite integrals. But that's how the symbology of a definite integral is defined, like the way the $+$ symbol is defined to be addition and not multiplication. If the question is why we prefer that definition over a definition where the $x$ of $\int dx$ can be used outside the integrand and still be the same variable, it's partly in order to avoid getting the answer $\frac12c$ in your question when the correct answer is obviously $\frac34c$ from the picture.